# Question about the degenerated ground states of a many body quantum system

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, phase-transition, many-body

The existence of degenerated ground states of a many-body quantum system is usually taken as a signature of the quantum order.

I am considering the follow question:

If we have a many-body quantum system with a Hamiltonian $H$, also we know its ground states are degenerated given by $\psi_1, \psi_2,...\psi_N$.

Can the $N$ different degenerated ground states be transformed to each other without phase transition?  Or in general these degenerated ground states may belong to different phases?

Comment: What do you mean by "transformed without phase transition"?  Which basis do you fix?  Otherwise, yes, you can design Hamiltonians which have ground states in different phases -- just couple a symmetry breaking model to two different topological models.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Could you please give me an example on 'couple a symmetry breaking model to two different topological models'? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding. But for me 'phase of a quantum state' is a property of the 'state' itself but not the Hamiltonian of the system. So if two  states $\psi_1,\psi_2$ of a quantum system belong to the same phase iff they can be connected by a gapped adiabatic evolution $H(g)$ with $\psi_1,\psi_2$ as the ground states of $H(0),H(1)$ respectively(Or equivalently they can be connected by a local unitary evolution).

Comment: So in my understanding, the states $\psi_1,...\psi_N$ belong to the same phase if they can evolve between each other by local unitary evolutions. So my question is : if the states $\psi_1,...\psi_N$ can be written as the degenerated ground states of some $H$, then they can be connected by local unitary evolutions. Or in another way, if there exists two states that can not be connected by a finite length quantum circuit, but they are the degenerated ground states of a gapped system.

Comment: Take an Ising ferromagnet.  Use the Ising variables as a control qubit to either activate a Toric Code Hamiltonian or a Double Semion Hamiltonian. (E.g. choose the local terms to be block-diagonal, with the two blocks the TC and DS Hamiltonian (shifted to be negative), and the block label the Ising spin.)   The system will have two sets of ground states, one with TC order and one with DS order.  ---  If such an example suffices as an answer, I might write one.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Yes please with more details. Thanks.

Comment: If this is true, then how to judge the phase of the superpositioned states of the  two states with different orders? Should this be regarded as a new phase?

Comment: Same as the symmetry-broken states in a ferromagnet: Superpositions of those are not stable and thus unphysical.  Differently speaking, the system is at a 1st order phase transition between those two topo phases.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Sorry, I do not understand why the superpositioned state is 'unphysical'. For me 'phase' is an inherent property of a certain quantum state, no matter if it's a ground state of some Hamiltonian. If we have two states $\psi_1,\psi_2$ in different phases, then what's the phase of  their superpositioned state? Or from the 'computational complexity' point of view of Wen, generally the superpositioned state can not be reached from either of $\psi_1,psi_2$ with a finite depth quantum circuit.  Do you mean those states with a certain quantum order are special?

Comment: I did read something like 'low-energy states of realistic Hamiltonians are not just “any” state in the Hilbert space: they are heavily constrained by locality so that they must obey the entanglement area-law.'(by Roman Orus in his paper about tensor networks).  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch If you define 'physical state' as  a state that 'can be reached from a fixed initial state with a finite length quantum circuit' by F. Verstraete, then the toric code is not 'physical' for a large qubit number N since the string net condensation state can not be reached by a quantum circuit (though it can be represented by tensor networks or DBMs).

Comment: @X.Dong I think you might be confusing the definition of "phase" in a wavefunction sense (i.e. the factor $e^{i\phi}$ that accompanies a state) with the definition of "phase" in a condensed-matter sense (i.e. a set of properties of matter that persists over a certain temperature and pressure range). They are called the same thing, but are two completely different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

We usually define a Hamiltonian to be in a particular phase, not a single quantum state. Specifically, we consider the space of all possible (local) Hamiltonians $H(\{g\})$ with all possible local coupling constants $g$, and consider the free energy density in the thermodynamic limit
$$f(\{g\}, T) := \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{-T \ln \left( \text{Tr } e^{-H(\{g\})/T} \right)}{N}$$
where $N$ is the system size. The phase boundaries are the points in Hamiltonian parameter space where $f$ depends non-analytically on $T$ or on one of the coupling constants $g$. So you can't talk about transform one state to another with or without a phase transition, only transforming Hamiltonians.

A well-posed (but different) question is whether the ground states of a Hamiltonian must always be connected by local unitary transformations. For a Hamiltonian in the topologically trivial phase, the answer is yes. For a topologically ordered Hamiltonian, the answer is no.